# is it necessarily true that the partition function $Z$ (with degeneracies) $ =1$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, partition-function, density-of-states

The partition function with degnerate energies is

$$\text{Z}=\sum _ig_ie^{{-E_i}/{k_BT}}.$$

Because the partition function Z is defined as the normalisation constant, does Z always = 1?

Comment: I deleted a few comments; remember, folks, answers should be posted as answers, not as comments.

Answer (score 3):

The partition function is not in general equal to one.
It is a normalization constant, i.e. the probability of being in a configuration $\{\sigma\}$ is
$$
P(\{\sigma\}) = \frac{e^{-H(\{\sigma\})/k_B T}}{Z}
$$
where 
$$
Z(T) = \sum_{\{\sigma\}} e^{-H(\{\sigma\})/k_B T}
$$
Since multiple configuration can have the same energy, you can define (with a little abuse of notation for the delta distribution)
$$
g_i = \sum_{\{\sigma\}} \delta( H(\{\sigma\} - E_i )
$$
which count the number of configurations with energy $E_i$. You can than write $Z$ as
$$
Z(T) = \sum_{\{\sigma\}} \sum_{i} \delta( H(\{\sigma\} - E_i ) e^{-H(\{\sigma\})/k_B T} = \sum_{i} g_i e^{-E_i/k_B T}
$$

$Z$ is a function of the temperature $T$. On the other side, the energy is always defined up to an additive constant, which means that $Z(T)$ is defined up to a multiplicative constant. This means that you are free to define $Z=1$ for a given temperature (it correspond to add a constant to the energy), but the the partition function will be different from one at different values of temperature. 
This has no effect on the observable physical quantities as they are derivative of $\log(Z)$

Comment: Would love to mark this as an accepted answer but the use of notation isn't very helpful.
Nevertheless, Thank you.