# What is the definition of 'relative population' in context of partition function?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, definition, probability, partition-function, density-of-states

In statistical mechanics, what is the definition (or mathematical definition) when authors refer to [relative population](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=statistical+physics&as_epq=relative+population) in the case of a classical particle system?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/182735/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a classical Maxwell-Boltzmann gas, the partition function is given by
$$Z=\sum_i g_i e^{-\beta \epsilon_i}$$
where $g_i$ is the degeneracy. And the probability for each level to be occupied by one particle is given by
$$P_i=\frac{g_i e^{-\beta \epsilon_i}}{Z}$$
The partition function function in the above expression is essentially a normalization factor for the probability, which can be ignored if you talk about relative population (or relative chance of being occupied). More precisely, the relative population of level $i$ with respect to level $j$ would just be
$$\frac{g_i e^{-\beta \epsilon_i}}{g_je^{-\beta \epsilon_j}}=\frac{g_i}{g_j}e^{-\beta(\epsilon_i-\epsilon_j)}$$
which is simply the ratio between the Boltzmann factors with degeneracies included.

Comment: The term "normalisation factor" popped up a couple of times, in my study of the text and in the replies to my question prior. What is a normalisation factor?

Comment: let's say, you have a box containing 1 white ball and 2 red balls and you randomly pick one from the box. Obviously the chance you get red is twice of that you get white. This is where people actually use the concept of probability to characterize the likelihood of some event and the convention is that the probabilities for all the possible events sum up to be 1. Following this convention, we would say, the probability for white is 1/3 and for red is 2/3

Comment: In this case, the total number of balls 3 becomes the normalization factor (or just an overall scaling factor in order to make the total probability 1)